# Oh, this puzzle

Tags: riddle, cipher, rhyme

> *Oh, this puzzle.*
>
> *To prevent you from answering it, I have a muzzle.*
>
> *Relax on that sofa, and nuzzle.*
>
> *The answer to this puzzle, is subtle.*
>
> *It shall make your brain shuttle.*
>
> *From Point A to Point B, you will scuttle.*
>
> *The key is the margin.*
>
> *Like a wall, that you barge in.*
>
> *Oh, that doesn't make sense.*
>
> *Let me help you, turn J into I, and commence!*
>
> *Before I forget, the funny slang is the key word, isn't that just common sense? And ignore this line's margin!*

Using the above poem, decrypt the phrase below

**`ETLN DI GIHILKF ILFANON, cpek'b ocf?`**

Comment: Seems like playfair

Comment: @greenturtle3141 You're close, but it's not exactly playfair.

Comment: Similar to playfair would be [two](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-square_cipher)-/[four](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-square_cipher)-square cipher.

Comment: @LukasRotter Close again, but it's not exactly that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution:

> `GOOD AT SOLVING CIPHERS, aren't you?`

Explanation:

> *"Margin"* refers to the first letters of each line of the riddle, except the last one, i.e. `otrtiftlol` (= `otrifl` with removed repetitions). Using this as a key in the [Bifid cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bifid_cipher) (as indicated by *"turn J into I"* and OP's comments under the question) you get the plaintext above.

Comment: Congrats, well done!